# vb.net - mysql query select record from month to month

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

how to search data from month to month if :

> txtbox1.text = "m/y" or "06/2013"
>
> txtbox2.text = "m/y" or "09/2013"

mysql query code :

> SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE dateregister ?.....

and if, record in table is:

> id name  dateregister
>
> 1   abc   05/05/2013
>
> 2   ccc   06/05/2013
>
> 3   ddd   01/06/2013
>
> 4   ggg   01/07/2013
>
> 5   ttt   10/07/2013
>
> 6   kkm   20/08/2013
>
> 7   ooo   01/09/2013

and I just wanted to take the data from month "06/2013" to "09/2013" and data that I get is:

> 3   ddd   01/06/2013
>
> 4   ggg   01/07/2013
>
> 5   ttt   10/07/2013
>
> 6   kkm   20/08/2013
>
> 7   ooo   01/09/2013

I've tried a variety of query but I always fail..

this is my code in vb.net :

> Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
>
> Dim connString As String = "Database=dbuser;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password="
>
> Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(connString)
>
> Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
>
> Dim ds As New DSReportPO
>
> Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
>
> monthx1= txtbox1.text
>
> monthx2 = txtbox2.text
>
> cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE dateregister?...", conn)
>
> adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
>
> adapter.Fill(ds.Tables(0))
>
> Frm1.Show()
>
> Frm1.ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local
>
> Frm1.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\Report1.rdlc"
>
> Frm1.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
>
> Frm1.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DSPOListSETUP", ds.Tables(0)))
>
> Frm1.ReportViewer1.DocumentMapCollapsed = True
>
> Frm1.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

thanks a lot

Comment: what is the data type of `dateregister` in your table?

Comment: @the data type i use for dataregister in database is varchar(45) and date is automaticly insert from vb.net code : txtdate = date.today

Comment: and it is in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`?

Comment: @491243 : sory, yes.. the format for date is "dd/mm/yyyy"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   STR_TO_DATE(dateregister, '%d/%m/%Y')
        BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01/', '06/2013'), '%d/%m/%Y') AND
                LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01/', '09/2013'), '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43d5e/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦══════╦══════════════╗
║ ID ║ NAME ║ DATEREGISTER ║
╠════╬══════╬══════════════╣
║  3 ║ ddd  ║ 01/06/2013   ║
║  4 ║ ggg  ║ 01/07/2013   ║
║  5 ║ ttt  ║ 10/07/2013   ║
║  6 ║ kkm  ║ 20/08/2013   ║
║  7 ║ ooo  ║ 01/09/2013   ║
╚════╩══════╩══════════════╝
```

Here's what happened to the query above, the column `dateregister` was converted into proper date using `STR_TO_DATE()` since it was saved as string in the format of `dd/mm/YYYY`.

Your input `06/2013` and `09/2013` were concatenated with `01/` and converted into date just like how the column `dateregister` was converted.

The function `LAST_DAY` takes a valid date and returns the last date of the month.

If you need faster performance in terms of searching for dates, you need to change the data type of column `dateregister` into `DATETIME or DATE` data type to avoid conversion.

Other References

- [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)
- [LAST_DAY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day)

---

```
monthx1= txtbox1.text
monthx2 = txtbox2.text
Dim  sqlQuery As new System.Text.StringBuilder
sqlQuery.Append("SELECT * " & vbCrLf)
sqlQuery.Append("FROM   tablename " & vbCrLf)
sqlQuery.Append("WHERE  Str_to_date(dateregister, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN " & vbCrLf)
sqlQuery.Append("       Str_to_date(Concat('01/', " & vbCrLf)
sqlQuery.Append("                   '" & monthx1 & "'), '%d/%m/%Y') AND Last_day( " & vbCrLf)
sqlQuery.Append("              Str_to_date(Concat('01/', " & vbCrLf)
sqlQuery.Append("                          '" & monthx2 & "'), '%d/%m/%Y')) ")
cmd = New MySqlCommand(sqlQuery.ToString(), conn)
```

Comment: thanks, I will try but it might take some improvement because after I copy and paste into vb.net there is some error.

Comment: see my updated answer, it's a quick fix, you should be parameterizing the value since it's from a textbox.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to use the `BETWEEN` keyword.

```
 SELECT * FROM tb_user 
 WHERE dateregister between @textBox1Value and @textBox2Value
```

Make sure the dates you parsing (@textBox1Value and  @textBox2Value) is well typed.

Refer to this link for the [date formatting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: thanks i've tried.. and and there is an error "MysqlException was unhandled" the code: cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE dateregister BETWEEN (@TextBox2.text and @TextBox3.text)", conn)adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
adapter.Fill(ds.Tables(0)) <- error in here

Comment: Your date should be well formatted. In your database also, your date should be of type `Datetime` as it make no sense to use the `between` when we using `varchar`. You can't have a condition saying between "PAUL" and "PAULA" :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BETWEEN` to find the date in range and use `DATE_FORMAT` to format date in query not sure about VB syntax

```
  SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE
  DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dateregister, '%d/%m/%Y'),'%m/%Y') 
  BETWEEN txtbox1.text AND  txtbox2.text
```

OR

```
  SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE
  DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dateregister, '%d/%m/%Y'),'%m/%Y') 
  BETWEEN '06/2013' AND  '09/2013'
```

[**Try this fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7eeef/2)

[**Mysql Date format**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: thanks, I've tried it.. no error but cannot give a result : The code that I use "SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dateregister,'%m/%Y') BETWEEN '%" & txtbox1.text & "%' and '%" & txtbox2.text & "%'"

Comment: @dianju : wow..in sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7eeef/2 it's works, but I have omitted the symbol % to '"& txtbox.text &"' and still no results, then I try to change '"& txtbox.text &"' directly with '06 / 2013 'and '09 / 2013 'and do not give result to.hmm.. what is wrong? but if I just look for the data in 1 month using MYSQL Query Code : SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE dateregister LIKE '%" & txtbox1.text & "%' I got it ..

Comment: @RiskiFebriansyah As i have provided the clear example in fiddle but i don't know the VB.net syntax so i can't tell you whats the problem :)

Comment: @RiskiFebriansyah try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i may it will help you

Answer (score 1):

The efficient way to handle TIME part also is to re-write the code as below

```
SELECT * FROM tb_user 
WHERE 
dateregister >= str_to_date(concat('01/',@textBox1Value ),'%d/%m/%Y') and 
dateregister < date_add(str_to_date(concat('01/',@textBox1Value ),'%d/%m/%Y'),interval 1 month)
```